# x,y coordinates of a JPanel as part of a quadrant

Tags: java, swing, geometry, java-2d

I'm having some problem with my program. what I want to implement is a way to understand a point(x,y) in which quadrant is located.

The concept of a quadrant that I'm trying to implement is the following: 
[image]

I have a rectangle, from which I have the coordinates of all the angles and the edges. given another point in the space, in the 2D space, I would like to know where is located between top,bottom, left and right.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

so far I've wrote this piece of code:

```
Point A=t.src;  //center point of the first square
Point B=t.dest;  //center point of the second square

int destHeight=t.destDim.height;
int destWidth=t.destDim.width;

int m = destHeight/destWidth;
int b = B.y -(m*B.x);
int d = B.y +(m*B.x);

if(A.y >= m*A.x +b){
    if(A.y >= -m*A.x+d){
        System.err.println("2 - Source on BOTTOM");
    }else{ //A.y < -m*A.x+d
        System.err.println("2 - Source on LEFT");
    } 
}else if(A.y < m*A.x + b){
    if(A.y>= -m*A.x +d){
        System.err.println("2 - Source on RIGHT");
    }else{ //A.y < m*A.x + d
        System.err.println("2 - Source on TOP");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I still don't have the expected result. This is what I get:
[Video demo of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-QUgtcuyVg&feature=youtu.be)

as you can see from the output console, it never pronts out that the source is on the left, it just transitions from top to bottom.

Comment: Do you struggle with math or Java?

Comment: I think it's mostly math. I don't know the concept so I can't think on how to code it

Comment: I recommend you this page rather: https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: oh, I didn't know about that. Thank you, I will.

Comment: You are welcome, sir. As soon as you need to help with Java or any programming related stuff, don't hesitate to ask here. :)

Comment: they did give me some explanations, I coded the answer given by fleablood, but i can't make it work. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2793481/x-y-coordinates-as-part-of-a-quadrant/2793484#2793560

Comment: If you need help with the implementation of that answer, edit this question with the code you have.

Comment: I posted the code, with a small video of the problem i have

Comment: `px =  A.x - B.x; py = A.y - B.y;` and follow my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let rectangle is zero-centered and has edge length `a` (horizontal) and `b`. (If it is not zero-centered, just subtract center coordinates from point ones). Then lines have simple equations

```
m = b / a 
y = m * x   //L1
y = -m * x  //L2
```

Point in top quadrant lies above both lines, point in right quadrant lies above L2 but below L1 and so on.

For point coordinates `(px, py)`:

```
 mpx = m * px
 if (py >= mpx) :
     if (py >= -mpx) :
          top
     else:
          left
 else:    
     if (py >= -mpx) :
          right
     else:
          bottom
```